# Zend Forms - populate() and setDefaults()

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms

Let's say I have a form that collects a first name and a last name:

```
$first_name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('first_name');
$first_name->setLabel("First Name")
    ->setRequired(true);

$last_name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('last_name');
$last_name->setLabel("Last Name")
    ->setRequired(true);

$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->addElement($first_name)
    ->addElement($last_name)
```

If I want to use the "populate($data)" or the "setDefaults($data)" method on the form, how does the array need to be organized? What kind of an array do these functions expect? I haven't been able to find this information in the docs.

Also, I know that I can set the value when creating the element itself, but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Array keys are the field names, array values are the field values.

```
$data = array( 'first_name' => 'Mickey', 'last_name' => 'Mouse' );
```

Answer (score 14):

The form->populate() method takes an array where the keys are the names of
the form fields.

The Zend_Db_Table_Row object implements a toArray() method which can be used
here (as do many other objects).  So you can do stuff like:

```
$form = new MyForm;

$table = new MyTable;
$rowset = $table->find($id);
$row = $rowset->current();

$form->populate($row->toArray());
```

Comment: +1 for giving a common use case. I'd say that in most cases populate() is called with this argument.

Answer (score 8):

FYI - in Zend_Form, `$form->populate($data)` just makes a call to `$form->setDefaults($data)`.

Comment: It can be quite educational to take a look at the Zend Framework source code now and then. Some pieces are quite complex, but a lot of it is actually understandable.

Answer (score 1):

simple, create an array

```
$data = array('nameInput'=> 'your value');
```

Add your form to your View

```
$this->view->form = $form;
```

then you add data to the form

```
$form->populate($data);
```