# Simple Zend Db function returning fatal error "Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object"

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

In my model I have the following function

```
protected $_users ='users'; 

public function getbyid($user_id)
{
$select = $this->_db
            ->select()
            ->from($this->_users)
            ->where('users.user_id =?', $user_id);


$result = $this->_db->fetchRow($select)->toArray();


return $result;
}
```

When it is called it returns fatal error :

```
Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object
```

Can anyone point in the direction of what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.
output of Zend_Debug::dump($this->_db->fetchRow($select));

```
array(11) {
["user_id"] => string(1) "1"
["role"] => string(13) "administrator"
["email"] => string(18) "bjh497@hotmail.com"
["password"] => string(40) "62bb49da919f0d349ed2cbbec559d7ed649dd238"
["created"] => string(19) "2013-05-09 07:34:00"
["modified"] => NULL
["status"] => string(6) "active"
["salt"] => string(40) "ce8d96d579d389e783f95b3772785783ea1a9854"
["lastlogin"] => NULL
["first_name"] => string(3) "Bob"
["last_name"] => string(5) "Smith"
}
```

Trying to use the result to populate a form in controller as follows

```
    $userdetails = new Account_Model_User;
    $userdetails->getbyid($user->user_id);
    $userdetails = $userdetails;
    $form = new Account_Form_Profile; 
    $form->populate($userdetails);
```

Comment: Can you print the result of `Zend_Debug::dump($this->_db->fetchRow($select));` without calling `toArray()`?

Comment: Zend_Debug::dump($this->_db->fetchRow($select));

array(11) {
  ["user_id"] => string(1) "1"
  ["role"] => string(13) "administrator"
  ["email"] => string(18) "bjh497@hotmail.com"
  ["password"] => string(40) "62bb49da919f0d349ed2cbbec559d7ed649dd238"
  ["created"] => string(19) "2013-05-09 07:34:00"
  ["modified"] => NULL
  ["status"] => string(6) "active"
  ["salt"] => string(40) "ce8d96d579d389e783f95b3772785783ea1a9854"
  ["lastlogin"] => NULL
  ["first_name"] => string(3) "Bob"
  ["last_name"] => string(5) "Smith"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of that `Zend_Debug::dump` call, `$this->_db->fetchRow($select)` already returns and array, so if you call `toArray()` it will throw the error you mentioned.

It all depends on what you want your `getbyid` function to return, but I'd say to simply update your code to:

```
protected $_users ='users'; 

public function getbyid($user_id)
{
    $select = $this->_db
                   ->select()
                   ->from($this->_users)
                   ->where('users.user_id =?', $user_id);

    $result = $this->_db->fetchRow($select);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the data to populate a form, as you mentioned fetchrow returns an array.

when I populate using the returned result in controller it fails with error :-
   
    Argument 1 passed to Zend_Form::populate() must be an array, object given

Comment: Update your question with the code where you instantiate the form, call `getbyid` and use `$result` on `Zend_Form::populate()`. Btw, are you sure that the array keys from `getbyid` match the fields in the form you're trying to populate? Take a look at [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301889/zend-forms-populate-and-setdefaults).

Comment: cheers rolando, sometimes all you need is someone to make you go through the steps.
    $userdetails->getbyid($user->user_id);
should have been
$userdetails = $userdetails->getbyid($user->user_id);

Answer (score 0):

fetchRow() function return already an array so, you don't need to "cast it " to array.
and you can access it directly by something like

```
 $result = $this->_db->fetchRow($select);
//so now you can access or assign values to a variable 
$user_id=$result['user_id'];
```

Hope it my help.